# Subsetting elements of a vector in R

Tags: r, list

I have been trying to create a list with the coordinates of a vector which have the same values.

Example: for a vector `Points = (2, 2, 3, 6, 3, 6, 3)`, coordinates that have the same value are (1,2), (3, 5, 7) and (4,6). So the output should be something like

```
[[1]]
1 2

[[2]]
3 5 7

[[3]]
4 6
```

Just to contextualize the necessity of this function: I'm trying to simulate random walks with multiple starting points. Once any given chains hit each other, the one with smallest index will be update. The vector `Points` is the position of all the walks at some time step t. I need to verify, at each time step, which chains have the same value, in order to update just the one with smallest index. In this particular example, just chains 1, 3 and 4 would be updated at instant `t+1`.

Comment: So X,Y,W on 3 in position 2, Z,V on 9 in position 3. Are you saying 'index' is ...? And desired output would look like?

Comment: Are all vectors the same length? What do you want to do if they aren't?

Comment: @gung, yes all vectors should have the same length. I should have been more specific. 
I'm trying to run multiple random walks and if some of them coalesce, they move together thereafter. This I asked is about a way of checking if two or more walks have coalesced. 
I'll edit the question.

Comment: Try this `split(seq_along(Points), Points)`

Comment: @Khashaa looks great, why delete your answer? If you want to match OP's output exactly just wrap in `unname()`.

Comment: This is great! Thank you both for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
X = c(2, 3, 4 )
Y = c(4, 3 ,5)
Z = c(8, 8 , 9, 6)
W = c(3, 3, 7,4)
V = c(9, 9, 9,3) 

findeev<-function(vi){ #takes a list of vector(s) to extract from `allv`
  nms=paste("v",vi,sep="")
  ne=max(sapply(allv[vi],length)) #max number of elements
  ine=1:ne
  # Computes sd along the positions of all vetors
  rest=apply(cbind(sapply(allv[vi],function(vt)vt[ine])),1,sd)
  # determine if some vectors have the same value across a position
  resc=which(rest==0)
  if(length(resc)){ret=allv[vi];ret$pos=resc
  names(ret)[-length(ret)]<-nms
  ret} else invisible()
}

allv=list(X,Y,Z,W,V)
findeev(c(3,5)) #exmple

sol=list();j=1 # This contains all pairs
for(i in (length(allv)-1):2){
  # compare all combinations of vector using `findeev`
  res<-apply(t(combn(1:length(allv),i )),1,findeev)
  if(is.null(res))next #not found continues
  # eliminate NAs form list and assign that to sol[[j]]
  sol[[j]]<-Filter(Negate(function(x) is.null(unlist(x))), res)
  j=j+1
}
sol
```

You get:

```
> findeev(c(3,5))
$v3
[1] 8 8 9 6

$v5
[1] 9 9 9 3

$pos
[1] 3

> sol
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]]$v1
[1] 2 3 4

[[1]][[1]]$v2
[1] 4 3 5

[[1]][[1]]$v4
[1] 3 3 7 4

[[1]][[1]]$pos
[1] 2



[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[[2]][[1]]$v1
[1] 2 3 4

[[2]][[1]]$v2
[1] 4 3 5

[[2]][[1]]$pos
[1] 2


[[2]][[2]]
[[2]][[2]]$v1
[1] 2 3 4

[[2]][[2]]$v4
[1] 3 3 7 4

[[2]][[2]]$pos
[1] 2


[[2]][[3]]
[[2]][[3]]$v2
[1] 4 3 5

[[2]][[3]]$v4
[1] 3 3 7 4

[[2]][[3]]$pos
[1] 2


[[2]][[4]]
[[2]][[4]]$v3
[1] 8 8 9 6

[[2]][[4]]$v5
[1] 9 9 9 3

[[2]][[4]]$pos
[1] 3
```

Comment: Thank you for editing the answer. I'm having a hard time to understand the code, though. Could you add some comments to clarify the role of each piece of code? 
Also, if we were to create a "subset" of vectors that have a same value on a respective coordinate (ex, X, Y, W would form one subset, and Z, V another one) regardless of the index where it first occur, how could we modify the code?
Thanks again.